# Laravel: Redirect to a named route that has parameters in URL

Tags: routes, laravel, laravel-4

Can anyone explain how I redirect to a named route that uses a parameter in the URL?

I have the following code:

```php
    Route::put('{handle}', array(
        'as' => 'section.update',
        'uses' => 'Manneken\\Api\\SectionManager@update'
    ));

    Route::post('{handle}', function()
    {
        if (Input::has('method') && Input::get('method') === 'PUT') {
            Redirect::route('section.update', array(
                'handle' => ''
            ))->withInput();
        }
    });
```

So, I have a route using PUT that has `{handle}` in the URL, and if requested by POST, I want to redirect to that route. How do I pass the `{handle}` through?

Comment: +1 For pointing `Route::put`. Where did you find it by the way? *Laravel Documentation* doesn't seems to mention it. I can't figure out completely what `'{handle}'` does as a parameter in the `Route::post`. Can you point me in the right direction with a link or a brief explanation? I would appreciate it very much!

Comment: @yannishristofakis 'Put' requests are forged using a hidden field. But, they are managed with forms of type 'POST'.

Comment: @h4k1m Ok I think I'm an idiot or it was to late. When you say `'{handle}'` you mean the request that the routes handle, it's that right? Yes I know `PUT` request `DELETE`,`PATCH` *restful* stuff. Thnx, do you know any good source of information, other than the *Laravel Documentation* to suggest?

Comment: 1. Yes `'{handle}'` represent any request. 2. I think that [Nettuts](http://nettuts.com) has some good tutorials on laravel.

Comment: Yeah, `{handle}` is the name of any value passed as a request and would be used in the controller as `$handle` as far as I know. I put this to bed for a while and I'm only just getting back into Laravel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I figured it out, that I was missing the `$handle` in the closure function as a parameter.

I must say, it's great to see the helpful Laravel community at work. So many helpful hints and tips for me here. All these answers just blow me away, thanks so much!

Comment: Glad you got it sorted John. That's where twitter helps fill the gaps. :) To be fair this is more of an outpost for the Laravel community than a base. If you want that handle to be optional then you can also include a question mark `{handle?}`. and also set a default by passing it as a parameter to the closure: `function($handle == 'default')`. This may come in handy if you're looking to set a fallback URL.